# Django APIClient login not working

Tags: django, rest, authentication, frameworks, apiclient

I'm having problem authenticating with my Django Rest Framework API in Unit Unit Tests. The system works as expected when accessing it through the browser. I however receive a 401 HTTP status when sending a put request to the following class at the following endpoint:

```
class UserDetail(RetrieveModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)
    permission_classes = IsAuthenticated,
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

The test below is as follows:

```
class AccountTests(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(email="user1@test.com", password="password1", is_staff=True)
        self.user.save()
        self.user = CustomUser.objects.get(email="user1@test.com")
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_add_name(self):
        self.client.login(email="user1@test.com", password='password1')
        url = reverse('customuser-detail', args=(self.user.id,))
        data = {'first_name': 'test', 'last_name': 'user'}

        self.client.login(email="user1@test.com", password='password1')
        response = self.client.put(url, data, format='json')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When printing the response.data, I receive:

```
{u'detail': u'Authentication credentials were not provided.'}
```

The client.login(...) method returns true, but the credentials do not appear to be attached to the header. My experiments in the IsAuthenticated permission classes had an request.user = AnonymousUser. In the BasicAuthentication class, auth = None.

Am I missing something as regards to using BasicAuth in settings.py? Or even in the test itself?

Thanks.

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 8):

First, `{u'detail': u'Authentication credentials were not provided.'}` occurs when the credential that you "provide" doesn't match with models. (I think it is bad error message)

So, you should set user's password by `set_password()` method, because of encryption.

```
self.user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(email="user1@test.com", is_staff=True)
self.user.set_password("password1")
self.user.save()
```

or, you can use `force_login()` for testing.

```
self.client.force_login(
    user=User.objects.first(),
    backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' # one of your AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may need to use `force_authenticate()` method for logging in,

```
def test_add_name(self):
    self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)        
    ........
```

You may consider re-writing your test-case, maybe somewhat like this,

```
class AccountTests(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(email="user1@test.com", password="password1", is_staff=True)
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_add_name(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)

        url = reverse('customuser-detail', args=(self.user.id,))
        data = {'first_name': 'test', 'last_name': 'user'}
        response = self.client.put(url, data, format='json')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```