# Django Rest Framework APIClient does not parse query parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I am using `djangorestframework==3.3.3` and `Django==1.9.4`

I have a test where I want to check that query parameters processed correctly.

```
class TestResourceView(APITestCase):

    def test_view_process_query_params_correctly(self):
        client = APIClient()
        client.login(username='<username>', password='password')
        response = client.get('/api/v2/resource/1/users/?fields=first_name;last_name')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        # .... rest of the test ....
```

In my view I put `print` statement just to see if query parameters are parsed properly, but I get empty query dictionary:

```
class Resource(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        query_params = request.query_params
        print('Printing query params')
        print(query_params)
        # .... rest of the code ....

    def post(self, request):
        query_params = request.query_params
        print('Printing query params')
        print(query_params)
        # .... rest of the code ....
```

Result in terminal when running tests:

```
Printing query params
<QueryDict: {}>
```

In the same time if I test `post` request like this:

```
response = client.post('/api/v2/resource/1/users/?fields=first_name;last_name')
```

i get params incorrectly parsed:

```
Printing query params
<QueryDict: {'last_name': [''], 'fields': ['first_name']}>
```

What is the correct way of using `APIClient`? Or is this still a bug? Because there was already similar [issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1461)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that DRF wants the params in `data` not `args` like the Django test client.

This answer helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45183972/9512437

```
class AccountTests(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(email="user1@test.com", password="password1", is_staff=True)
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_add_name(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)

        url = reverse('customuser-detail', args=(self.user.id,))
        data = {'first_name': 'test', 'last_name': 'user'}
        response = self.client.put(url, data, format='json')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: I believe you might have misunderstood the question; it's asking about `query_params` not request data

Answer (score 0):

The format of your query parameters is incorrect.

If you want the result to be `{'fields': ['last_name', 'first_name']}`, then your POST url should be `.../users/?fields=first_name&fields=last_name'`. You'll probably want to access the params using [getlist()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist).

Comment: The idea is to get query params, and parse them the way I need. For example, there might be params like this `/api/v2/resource/1/users/?fields=first_name;last_name`, which will be parsed into the set `{'first_name', 'last_name'}`. One more option `/api/v2/resource/1/users/?fields=1-4`, which under the hood will be parsed into  the set `{'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'skype'}`. And still, another problem remains `client.get('/api/v2/resource/1/users/?fields=first_name;last_name')` results in empty `query_params`

Answer (score 0):

1) Regarding empty `<QueryDict: {}>` in `client.get('/api/v2/resource/1/users/?fields=first_name;last_name')` - there was my mistake in my code. I had two tests with the same name, one of which indeed has empty `<QueryDict: {}>`. So, when running tests, django ran the test with `<QueryDict: {}>`

2) Regarding incorrect parsing of query params in `client.post('/api/v2/resource/1/users/?fields=first_name;last_name')`, I found the following [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/BFPO-kcVnIA). So, django basically follows HTTP standards, where it is said that `;` semicolon is reserved character and if using, than the correct way to comprehend it same as `&`. Here more [details](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)